# How can I get the size of bloom filter set while using union or intersection function?

Tags: python, approximation, bloom-filter

I'm trying to get the size of bloom filter set while using bloom filter's union & intersection functions with python package(https://github.com/jaybaird/python-bloomfilter.git)

I though that after conducting the function 'union' or 'intersection', then I could get the result by adding len() function, but it just print out only '0' output.

```
from pybloom import BloomFilter
bf1 = BloomFilter(1000)
bf2 = BloomFilter(1000)

# After adding some elements to bf1 and bf2
print(len(bf1.union(bf2)))
# expected max(len(bf1), len(bf2)) but the result was 0
```

After I find the document page, I realized that the len() option become disabled after 'union' function and its actual result len() was 0.

Instead, I want to approximate the size of bloom filter set somehow.
Do you have any idea in order to calculate the size of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The implementation only copies BloomFilter's [bitarray](https://github.com/jaybaird/python-bloomfilter/blob/master/pybloom/pybloom.py#L216), i.e. `self.bitarray`. The elements `self.count` in [previous filters](https://github.com/jaybaird/python-bloomfilter/blob/master/pybloom/pybloom.py#L170) are not counted in.

So it doesn't union the elements - but do a bitarray `or`.

---

**Update:**

In most cases you don't need to approximate the count. It provided a [precise count](https://github.com/jaybaird/python-bloomfilter/blob/master/pybloom/pybloom.py#L200) of elements when you call `add`, and you can just call `len(bf3)`. Unfortunately new created `bf3` has not been called `add` so `len(bf3) == 0`.

For the formula to approximate number of elements,

```
- m / k * ln(1- n / m)
```

You have

```
import math.log as ln

m = bf3.bitarray.length()
n = bf3.bitarray.count()
k = bf3.num_slices

# given m=20, n=8, approximate n elements as 5.89
```

Comment: I checked that the implementation only copies bitarray and thanks for notifying me it. However, my question is approximation size of set mentioned below.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter#The_union_and_intersection_of_sets

Comment: @ahnpersie sorry I spent some time to get it right. A link I referenced was wrong. And I also added an approximation method to the question. You may extend the class and wrap it as a class method.

Comment: @knk190 That's exactly what I want. Thanks!
Also I find the exact value of variable k. (the code you found from wikipedia is just ideal value I think) 
```k = bf3.num_slices```